# Display subtotal in EXCEL pivot CHART

Tags: excel, charts, pivot, subtotal

Hi there and thanks in advance for all of you who'll help me on this dead end (for me).

My issue is quite simple to explain: I want to display subtotals on my Excel Pivot Chart, like a line showing the total of the categories.

Here is what I have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/16fhL.png

and here is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEFt7.png

I simply want to add on the graph the line corresponding to "TOTAL BEFORE".
I've been searching on the web ginving one workarround doing and simple chart on the pivot table; but it's not sustainable as the graph cannot follow when I change the pivot table filter.
I cannot figure out why there is not a simple way to add the subtotal in the list field of the chart.

Thanks for your precious help...